# Ionic2 - No page transitions on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an application using Ionic2, and it seems that there is no transition for `ion-nav` for iOS (both device and browser device mode). Also it seems that transition click blocker is not working, so you can bug your app clicking too fast.

Has anyone faced this problem already?

Comment: Now youv'e mentioned bugging the app with multiple clicks I just tested mine and it does the same thing (for me it was opening a child page for the first time and multiple clicks opened it multiple times). Sounds like an issue that needs raising on their github issues page!! https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues

Comment: Glad it's not happening in my case only :) Android transitions are cutting-edge, but iOS seems to be bugged. I wouldn't be concerned about visuals if transitions wouldn't break application.